# YOLO V5 score of prediction

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I managed to train the YOLO V5 model on my customed data and I'm having great results. I am able to export the bonding boxes in a txt file in which I have their coordinates.

I want to get also the score of prediction, but I don't know if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using this command :

```
!python detect.py --weights .../best.pt --img 416 --conf 0.2 --source .../images --save-txt --save-conf
```